# How to migrate unencryped realm to encrypt realm

Tags: android, realm

My last release app is using not encrypted realm.
Now, I want to update to use encrypted realm.

But I don't know how to migrate unencrypted data.

Help me please~ :(

Comment: My guess is you'll need a Migration (https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations). When you perform this operation you can setup the new Realm file with the configs you'd like –encryption included.

Comment: @Orlando You mean that I should change realm name?? Can I retain unencrypted realm name??

Comment: No, the migration allows you to create a new Realm database and copy data from another previously existing Realm db. You will pick a new name for the database being created, but at the end the name is irrelevant. After the migration to the encrypted Realm is perfomed you could also change the new Realm name to match the previous name, that's on you.

Answer (score 6):

Answer by myself.
I made util class to help migration. (unecncrypted file -> encrpyted file)

```
public class RealmEncryptionHelper {
    private static final String ENCRYPTION_FILE_PREFIX = "encrypted_";

    public static Realm createEncryptedRealm(Context context, RealmConfiguration.Builder builder) {
        RealmConfiguration unencryptedConfig = builder.build();

        RealmConfiguration encryptedConfig = builder.name(ENCRYPTION_FILE_PREFIX + unencryptedConfig.getRealmFileName())
                .encryptionKey(AppSharedPreferences.getInstance(context).getRealmEncryptionKey())
                .build();

        migrationIfNeeded(unencryptedConfig, encryptedConfig);

        return Realm.getInstance(encryptedConfig);
    }

    private static void migrationIfNeeded(RealmConfiguration unencryptedConfig, RealmConfiguration encryptedConfig) {
        File unencryptedFile = new File(unencryptedConfig.getPath());
        File encryptedFile = new File(encryptedConfig.getPath());

        Realm unencryptedRealm = null;
        if (!encryptedFile.exists() && unencryptedFile.exists()) {
            try {
                unencryptedRealm = Realm.getInstance(unencryptedConfig);
                unencryptedRealm.writeEncryptedCopyTo(encryptedFile, encryptedConfig.getEncryptionKey());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (unencryptedRealm != null) {
                    unencryptedRealm.close();
                    unencryptedFile.delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about [writeEncryptedCopyTo](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#writeEncryptedCopyTo-java.io.File-byte:A-). Nice find.

Answer (score 0):

@Orlando

like this?

```
class EncryptionMigration implements RealmMigration {
    @Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm dynamicRealm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        byte[] encryptionKey = "flkajskdf............................".getBytes();

        if (oldVersion == UNENCRYPT_VERSION) {
            try {
                dynamicRealm.writeEncryptedCopyTo(new File(dynamicRealm.getPath()), encryptionKey);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```